# Warning Division By zero

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

I'm building support decision system using electre method
While i compile my code i got an error
the error is : Warning Division By zero
Here is the function that i created

```
function normalisasi(){
    $array = ratarata();
    $arr = spk_rel();
    $nilai = array();
    $data = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $nilai[$key]=sqrt(array_sum($value));
    }
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){                
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
           $data[$key][$k] = $v / $nilai[$k];
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The error is in

```
$data[$key][$k] = $v / $nilai[$k];
```

could you please help me ?

Comment: What should be set in `$data[$key][$k]` if `$nilai[$k]` is 0?

Comment: this indicates a flaw in your data or your logic behind the data, or both.  Fix that first.  `ratarata`

Answer (score 1):

You will get a error when you divide any by 0.

You should check $nilai[$k] before make a divide by 0.

```
if (!empty($nilai[$k])) {
  $data[$key][$k] = $v / $nilai[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified what the logic is about, but if you're expecting some values of `$nilai` to be 0 and you can just skip them, there 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Checking for value inside loop

```php
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){                
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
           if ($nilai[$k]) {
               $data[$key][$k] = $v / $nilai[$k];
           }
        }
    }
```

This expression `if ($nilai[$k])` will be true when `$nilai[$k]` is either positive or negative and will be false when it's 0.

2. You can remove 0 values from `$nilai` array before loop

```php
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $nilai[$key]=sqrt(array_sum($value));
    }

    $nilay = array_filter($nilay);

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        ...
    }
```

In this case `array_filter` called without second argument (filter callback) will just remove all 0 values from array passed as first argument.